# Android studio drawable Shape line расположение

Tags: android, android-drawable

Не могу понять как расположить shape линию ниже обычного его расположения(если его просто вставить, то получается горизонтальная линия ровно по середине кнопки, перечеркивающая надпись внутри), а мне нужно чтобы она ниже надписи шла. Как это делается ?
Вот кусок кода, но тут ничего серьезного :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    >
    <shape
        android:shape="line"
        >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000">
        </stroke>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что надо было использовать layer-list, а не selector. Он позволяет двигать элементы внутри, как нужно

Comment: Тут принято оформлять ответ с решением. Оформите ответ правильно и с кодом, возможно это поможет другим с подобным вопросом.